# How to use the Law of Sines to Find an Angle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, triangles, angle

I am trying to figure out how to find an angle with the law of sines.

I have a triangle where:

A = $120^\circ$

B = unmarked

C = $\theta$

a = 45

b = unmarked

c = 36

How can I find the angle for C?

I have tried:

$$\frac{sin120^\circ}{45} = \frac{sinB}{b} =\frac{sin\theta}{36} $$

$$36(\frac{sin\theta}{36}) = 36(\frac{sin120^\circ}{45})$$
$$sin\theta = \frac{36sin120^\circ}{45}$$
$$ \theta = \frac{36(120^\circ)}{45} = 95^\circ$$

But, the answer is supposed to be $44^\circ$.

Comment: A sin is missed in your last line!

Comment: I just dropped the sin altogether. If that's not what I do, then I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: $$\sin(\theta)=\frac{36}{45}\sin(120^{\circ})\approx 43.853..$$

Comment: Hint: $$\sin(120^{\circ})=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Comment: I have added some comments for you!

Comment: @Graubner according to my calculator $\frac{36}{45}\sin(120^{\circ})\approx 0.6928..$

Comment: This is right! and the searched angle is given by $$\theta \approx 43.85^{\circ}$$

Comment: @Graubner I am not sure what you mean. How did you get $\theta$ from that?

Comment: You must press the inv sin bottom on your calculator.

Comment: ohh, so $\sin^-^1(\frac{36}{45}\sin(120^{\circ}))\approx 43.853..$

Comment: Congratulations, you got it!

Comment: thanks! This really helped!

Comment: I wish you a nice evening, good night!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following step is completely wrong

$$\sin\theta = \frac{36 \sin120^\circ}{45} \iff \color{red}{\theta = \frac{36(120^\circ)}{45} = 95^\circ}$$

we have that $\sin120^\circ=\sqrt 3/2$ and then

$$\sin\theta = \frac{36\sin120^\circ}{45} \iff \sin \theta = \frac{36\sqrt 3}{2\cdot 45} \iff \theta = \arcsin \left(\frac{2\sqrt 3}{9}\right)$$

Comment: I'm sorry, my class hasn't covered arcsin yet. Could you please show how to get the answer in degrees?

Comment: Note that $\arcsin x$ is the inverse function of $\sin x$, we need that to find the value for $\theta$ here. You should have itnon your calculator and you should also be able to obtain the result in degree directly or convrting by radians.

Comment: Note also that in that case we can use $\arcsin x$ to obtain the result because we are sure that the angle is acute otherwise, when the angle is obtuse, we need to take $\pi - \arcsin x$.

Answer (score 1):

Most of your steps are correct, but it is from the second last step you made a fundamental mistake.

Using arcsine ($sine^{-1}$ on calculator):

$$sin\theta = \frac{36sin120^\circ}{45} $$
$$\theta = arcsine(\frac{36sin120^\circ}{45}) $$
$$\theta = 43.8537^{\circ}... $$
$$\theta \approx 44^{\circ} $$

Just as @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner pointed out. The mistake you made was that you interpreted arcsine and sin$\theta$ canceling out, because sometimes it is learned to students that $arcsine = \frac{1}{sin}$. The thing is, $sin$ on itself cannot be cancelled out, as it is a trigonometric function of an angle, not $s . i . n$ as variables.

Comment: Ah, I took to long to post a comment. At least @gimusi got to it!